# My Firebase database isn't getting written to from my android kotlin app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am unable to write to my firebase database even when my "setValue" is called successfully from this kotlin code:

```
class InsertActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // get the database reference
    private var firebaseDatabase: FirebaseDatabase? = null
    private var databaseReference: DatabaseReference? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert)

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase!!.reference.child("traveldeals")


    }



    private fun saveDeal() {
        val title = txtTitle.text.toString().trim()
        val description = txtDescription.text.toString().trim()
        val price = txtPrice.text.toString().trim()

        val travelDeal = TravelDeal(title, description, price, "")

        // save data into firebase
        databaseReference!!.push().setValue(travelDeal)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { ex : Exception ->
                Log.d("TAG", ex.toString())

            }

    }
}
```

I have added the need gradle dependencies and also added the authentication credentials in the firebase console as directed, I see no errors in the app but the database isn't been created and I have also made the database writable and readable.

I see this:

> 2019-08-01 19:05:23.206 5065-5065/com.connect.systems.ng.travelmantics I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful

in my android studio logcat.

Comment: Have you added the `google-services.json` file in app level folder ?

Comment: Yes I have as part of the setup process.

Comment: And is the success toast showing up or the failure log?

Comment: Way you using push() before setValue()? check this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: the success toast is the one showing

Answer (score 0):

You're pushing values before setting them.

From the docs:

```
databaseReference!!.setValue(user)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            // Write was successful!
            // ...
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            // Write failed
            // ...
        }
```

So your code should be something like:

```
databaseReference!!.setValue(travelDeal)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }
            .addOnFailureListener { ex : Exception ->
                Log.d("TAG", ex.toString())

            }
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Is the push not supposed to come after the set?

Comment: Can't see that mentioned in docs. Above snippet isn't working?

Comment: Found the issue my class TravelDeal wasn't setup right

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue my class TravelDeal wasn't setup right formally was declared like this:

```
class TravelDeal() {

    var id : String? = null
    var title : String? = null
    var description : String? = null
    var price : String? = null
    var imageUrl : String? = null

    // The this sets the above fields to the constructor parameters
    constructor(title: String, description: String, price: String, imageUrl: String?) : this()

}
```

Then using the link provided by @AnasMehar I change it to this:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
class TravelDeal(
    var title: String? = "",
    var description: String? = "",
    var price: String? = "",
    var imageUrl: String? = ""
)
```